# RadzenTemplateForm keydown event not working in Chrome and Edge

Tags: keydown, preventdefault, radzen

I'm encountering an issue with the RadzenTemplateForm component where the keydown event is not functioning as expected in Chrome and Edge browsers. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<RadzenTemplateForm Data="@_Contract" @onkeydown:preventDefault="shouldPreventDefault">
    <!-- Form content goes here -->
    </RadzenTemplateForm>

    @code {
    private bool shouldPreventDefault = true;
   }
```

In Firefox, the keydown event works as intended, but in Chrome and Edge, it does not seem to be firing at all. I've checked the browser console for any errors, but there are no relevant messages.

I've also ensured that I'm using the latest version of the RadzenTemplateForm component and have tested in incognito mode to rule out any interference from browser extensions.

Is there a known issue with the RadzenTemplateForm component in Chrome and Edge, or is there something specific I need to do to ensure compatibility across browsers? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.